# Why the non-monochrome background?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design

After a few minutes, I've come to strongly dislike the dots on the background. Why not just a pure white?

(If it's just me, I suppose it's easily fixed in my user CSS.)

Comment: P.S. Jin, in spite of my nitpicks, I do like the design, thanks!

Comment: I didn't even notice.

Comment: @Tshepang I didn't either; I have trouble seeing it even when I'm looking. On the other hand, I barely see the blue background on interesting-tagged posts

Comment: I always thought something was wrong with my screen, barely visible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. It should be barely visible. Judging by your other design related reports, it seems your monitor's gamma is a bit off. Are you having the same problem when visiting the site from other computers?

Comment: Even though the texture is barely visible, I still think it is not an appealing texture - enough so that no texture would be better. Perhaps a similarly low-contrast texture that is something other than dots would work? I tried very light both 1px and 2px horizontal strips and found them slightly better, but there is almost certainly something better we could do.

Comment: I've now tried on a few different monitors, and the dots bother me on the monitors that I find the most comfortable. My gamma is probably off: I read text all day and never need accurate color rendering, so I chose settings that were good for reading text. [User CSS it is.](http://superuser.com/questions/234952/understanding-css-for-user-styling-in-a-browser)